# Работа с Jsoup, AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Всем доброго времени суток. Я пока еще совсем новичок, совсем запутался, прошу вашей помощи. Код:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button mButton;
    EditText mEditText;
    TextView mTextView;
    Parser par;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mEditText);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = mEditText.getText().toString();
                par = new Parser(code);
                par.execute();

            }
        });
    }
}

class Parser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    public Parser(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    String link;
    String code;
    String firstlink;
    String secondlink;
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        Document doc = null;


        link = "http://meteoinfo.by/radar/?q=" + code;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (doc != null) {
            firstlink = doc.select("td img[border=\"0\"]").attr("src");
            secondlink = "http://meteoinfo.by/radar" + firstlink.replaceFirst("\\.", "");
        } else
            secondlink = "Ошибка";

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTextView.setText(secondlink);
    }

}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как отправить `code` из `mEditText` в класс `parser`, чтоб он его обработал и на выходе получить спарсеное `secondlink` и вставить в `mTextView`.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.pollux.test2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mTextView"
        android:text="link must be here"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="get link"
        android:id="@+id/mButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RUKL"
        android:id="@+id/mEditText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать\посмотреть урок по `AsyncTask`. Если кто-то вместо вас напишет этот код, вы ничему не научитесь. Лучше разберитесь сами. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20asynctask%20tutorial

Comment: @metalurgus уроки это конечно обязательное дело, но и когда пример кода разбираешь, особенно свои наработки, то еще лучше понимается. Если Вам не составит труда, пожалуйста, помогите с данным кодом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете передать нужные данные через конструктор:

```
class parser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String code;

    public parser(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    ...
}
```

Вызывать задачу, соответственно, так:

```
 new parser(code).execute();
```

Обращаться же к UI надо в методе `onPostExecute()` - именно в нём можно назначить что-либо.

---

При этом в данный момент у вас видно непонимание работы `AsyncTask` - лучше его делать в отдельном классе и передать в него класс, реализующий интерфейс (активити, например), коий и должен будет отвечать за назначение текста в виджет.

Также, классы в Java именуются с большой буквы.

Comment: спасибо за совет. Обновил первый пост, вроде бы ничего, но почему то в методе `onPostExecute()` не работает строка `mTextView.setText(secondlink)` подчеркивает красным `mTextView`. Вроде все как в [уроке](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html), но что то видимо не так

Comment: @Pollux, наведите на это место и появится подсказка с типом ошибки

Comment: Естественно наводил, ошибка "cannot resolve symbol `mTextView`", перепроверил код, прошелся по гуглу у кого такое было, вроде все в порядке. Скорее всего, только для меня в коде все в порядке)

Comment: @Pollux, вообще, вроде, переменная должна быть видна... Но, коли нет, то попробуцте её также серез конструктор передать. Это плохой подход, но сработать должно.

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял добавил так: в конструктор `public Parser(String code, String mTextView)` добавил строку `this.mTextView = mTextView;`, но и тут она (`mTextView `) красная с той же ошибкой. Может попробуйте, если не затруднит, у себя в редакторе этот код. Выше приложил xml.

Comment: @Pollux, mTextView это не строка, но текстовое поле. Поменяйте тип на `TextView`

Comment: Изменил на `public Parser(String code, TextView mTextView)`, без изменений... =(

Comment: @Pollux, не может такого быть) Поправьте код в вопросе с учётом изменений - посмотрю

Comment: Юрий, подчеркивание пропало, после объявления в `class Parser` типа `TextView mTextView;`, но с другой стороны зачем в `Parser` объявлять еще раз, если это уже сделано в основном классе, да и в уроках такого не видел... Выше отредактировал java-код и xml, которые на текущий момент якобы без ошибок. После компиляции приложение запускается, но после нажатия на кнопку крашится...=( Видимо добавлением этой строки просто скрылась эта ошибка для редактора. В mEditText оставил код RUKL он верный, на выходе `secondlink` должна быть ссылка на png.

Comment: Вы не передали ссылку на textview через конструктор и у вас NPE. Всегда говорите о типе ошибки и месте её возникновения

Comment: Юрий, премного Вам благодарен за помощь и разъяснения мне, новичку. Все отлично работает! Но, заметьте, в [этом уроке](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/150-urok-87-asynctask-parametry-promezhutochnye-rezultaty.html), на который я опирался, нет таких объявлений, только один раз в главном классе и вроде конструктора такого нет, как в нашем случае и там все работает =)

Comment: @Pollux, пожалуйста) Вы можете отметить ответ "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела поста. А у вас не работало потому, что вы неверно скопировали пример. Конкретно - у вас класс-задача описан вне класса активити и, засим, не имеет доступа к его переменным. Т.е. вам надо было просто его вырезать и вставить перед закрывающей фигурной скобкой класса активити.

Comment: Вот оно что оказывается... У меня то было убеждение, что класс не может быть внутри другого класса, т.е они должны быть по отдельности.

Comment: @Pollux, ну, теперь знаете, что могут. Но там много нюансов, у вложенных классов. Например они не могут быть public, если они при этом не static, но в этом случае доступа к нестатическим переменным объемлющего класса у них не будет. В общем в виде примера можно запихнуть класс-задачув класс-активити, но вообще так не делают, да и сам AsyncTask не используют, т.к. он устарел и не дружит с пересозданием активити при повороте экрана.Если задача завершится только после того, как вы экран повернёте, то приложение упадёт, т.к. задача попытается присвоить текст TextView уже мёртвой активити.

Comment: Получается мне, как начинающему, лучше сразу привыкать каждый класс делать отдельно? Насчет устаревшего AsyncTask не осведомлен, использовал его т.к в описании к библиотеке Jsoup, да и в примерах, был этот класс.

Comment: @Pollux, в большинстве случаев да - один класс=один файл. А AsyncTask... Ну, просто это самый простой способ быстро сделать запрос в сеть без подключения разных библиотек и изучения разных других штук. Как альтернативу могу посоветовать OkHttp либу - с ней есть способ сделать запрос в сеть без создания новых классов-задач. Но это надо библиотеку подключать и мануалы по ней смотреть.

Comment: Библиотеки я уже подключал, поэтому если все стандартно, то подключится, спасибо, гляну на гитхабе. Один класс = один файл это очень хорошо в плане порядка, но эти геттеры-сеттеры меня вчера свели с ума (пробовал на простом примере передать-посчитать площадь a*b), поэтому в данном случае буду следовать принципу "работает - не трогай" =)